# Изменения значения в двумерном массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив товаров

```
array(2) {[0]=>array(11) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "2"
["article"]=>
string(1) "0"
["name"]=>
string(15) "Etiam Tristique"
["description"]=>
string(512) "HTC Touch - in High Definition. Watch music videos and streaming content in."
["price"]=>
string(3) "120"
["url_img"]=>
string(22) "/webroot/img/toy/2.jpg"
["sklad"]=>
string(1) "1"
["brend"]=>
string(4) "ewfe"
["other"]=>
string(3) "toy"
["time"]=>
string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
["kol"]=>
int(1)  }


[1]=>  array(11) {
["id"]=>
string(1) "3"
["article"]=>
string(1) "0"
["name"]=>
string(11) "Sed At Ante"
["description"]=>
string(0) ""
["price"]=>
string(3) "152"
["url_img"]=>
string(22) "/webroot/img/toy/3.jpg"
["sklad"]=>
string(1) "1"
["brend"]=>
string(3) "wef"
["other"]=>
string(3) "toy"
["time"]=>
NULL
["kol"]=>
int(3) } }
```

Как сделать, чтобы при отправке `GET`'ом количества товара (для конкретного `id`) изменялось количество товара в массиве (для конкретного `id`), а значение `kol` для других товаров оставалось тем же?

Нужно чтобы переписывалось `kol` для определенного `id` при каждой отправке формы с конкретным товаром и для его количества.

Comment: [работа с массивами](http://php.ru/manual/language.types.array.html), [циклы](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles)

Comment: Вы сами свой вопрос перечитайте и попробуйте понять

Comment: korytoff вероятно хочет сказать, что ваш вопрос сложен для понимания. Вы храните данные о товарах просто в массиве в памяти приложения? А что если оно упадёт, делать переучёт?

Comment: Нет, почему даные о товарах вытаскивается с БД, просто когда оформляется заказ вытаскиваются товары плюс добавляется поле количества

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оптимально - загнать массив в SQL и уже там выполнить UPDATE по id элемента

Comment: а если в ту же секунду будет заказ с теми ж товарами

Comment: а какое вообще количество товаров предполагается? если много, то работа по перебору массива в поисках нужного элемента будет совсем небыстрая и вы вернётесь к этому же вопросу: "а что будет если в ту же секунду будет заказ с теми ж товарами"

Comment: откуда возникла необходимость такого "странного" хранения данных?

Comment: А что Вы можете посоветовать. Можна как-то с Вами связатся (скайп, вивер) что бы помочь

Comment: @MykolaShkit: int03h@mail.ru